# Adding MVVM-Light templates to Visual Studio 2013

Tags: wpf, nuget, mvvm-light, visual-studio-2013

I have installed Visual Studio 2013 and have installed MVVM Light version 4.2.30 through Nuget. This does not install the templates for new mvvm projects or new mvvm files. How can I get these templates installed for 2013?

Comment: The error message probably means that the .vsix only works for VS2012 and not for VS2013.  You'll need to wait for a newer version.

Comment: I think I will update my question to clarify that I'm not trying to resolve that error, only wanting to know if I can get this functionality. I am guessing you are right that its just not ready yet.

Comment: The mvvmlight CodePlex page is now updated with a VS2013 vsix: http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/115541

Comment: MVVM Light can now be installed via the Code Gallery.